# Pandas resample FutureWarning

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a 1-Minute bar OHLC price CSV file that I am trying to resample to 15-Minute bars. The code that I am using is from this [link](http://sacbnctrading.blogspot.in/2016/10/convert-1m-ohlc-data-into-other.html), and is follows:

```
ohlc_dict = {'open':'first', 'high':'max', 'low':'min', 'close': 'last'}

price15m = df.resample('15Min', how=ohlc_dict, closed='right').dropna(how='any')
```

I am getting the expected resample dataframe, but this warning too:

```
FutureWarning: how in .resample() is deprecated
the new syntax is .resample(...)..apply(<func>)
  ohlc_dict = {'open':'first', 'high':'max', 'low':'min', 'close': 'last'}
```

The suggestion is to use this syntax but I am not sure how to:

```
the new syntax is .resample(...)..apply(<func>)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Resampler.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html):

```
price15m = df.resample('15Min', closed='right').agg(ohlc_dict).dropna(how='any')
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense.